# Generic Jolt Spec for Multiple Input JSON

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I m having difficulty in writing a jolt spec for different JSON inputs. I need to get a generic jolt spec so that i get a flattened json

Input 1 :

```json
[
  {
    "OrderInfo": [
      {
        "OrderHeader": {
          "orderType": "PULL",
          "customerPOType": "",
          "enteredDate": "20220324190249",
          "mitSect": "",
          "mitBillingFacility": "",
          "customerCode": "Z177",
          "mitAccNo": "",
          "userCWSId": "ANDERM2",
          "userName": "Michael Andersen",
          "rushFlag": 0,
          "customerPONumber": "",
          "mitPriorityIndicator": "",
          "mitOrderNumber": "",
          "customerFacilityCode": "JA",
          "GSIOrderNumber": "SHIVAM1000000100",
          "dtCode": "JADOJA",
          "mitRemarks": ""
        },
        "OrderDetails": [
          {
            "deliverToCoordinates": " SUPRA2RA",
            "exactQuantityFlag": "",
            "earlyShipDate": "20220324190249",
            "deliverToDockBuilding": "JA",
            "preferredWarehouseId": "SE92",
            "deliverToBuilding": "A2",
            "deliverToDropZoneArea": " A2A",
            "orderQuantity": 100,
            "orderMethod": "P",
            "plannedFirmIndicator": "F",
            "transactionType": "A",
            "lateShipDate": "",
            "crossdockFlag": 0,
            "deliverToArea": " A2A",
            "partNumber": "2T3001",
            "buildSequenceNumber": "",
            "deliverToDropZoneBuilding": "A2",
            "orderLineNumber": 1,
            "deliverToDockArea": "DOJA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "OrderHeader": {
          "orderType": "PULL",
          "customerPOType": "",
          "enteredDate": "20220324190249",
          "mitSect": "",
          "mitBillingFacility": "",
          "customerCode": "Z177",
          "mitAccNo": "",
          "userCWSId": "ANDERM2",
          "userName": "Michael Andersen",
          "rushFlag": 0,
          "customerPONumber": "",
          "mitPriorityIndicator": "",
          "mitOrderNumber": "",
          "customerFacilityCode": "JA",
          "GSIOrderNumber": "SHIVAM1000000100",
          "dtCode": "JADOJA",
          "mitRemarks": ""
        },
        "OrderDetails": [
          {
            "deliverToCoordinates": " SUPRA2RA",
            "exactQuantityFlag": "",
            "earlyShipDate": "20220324190249",
            "deliverToDockBuilding": "JA",
            "preferredWarehouseId": "SE92",
            "deliverToBuilding": "A2",
            "deliverToDropZoneArea": " A2A",
            "orderQuantity": 100,
            "orderMethod": "P",
            "plannedFirmIndicator": "F",
            "transactionType": "A",
            "lateShipDate": "",
            "crossdockFlag": 0,
            "deliverToArea": " A2A",
            "partNumber": "2T3001",
            "buildSequenceNumber": "",
            "deliverToDropZoneBuilding": "A2",
            "orderLineNumber": 1,
            "deliverToDockArea": "DOJA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Input 2 :

```json
[
  {
    "OrderInfo": [
      {
        "OrderHeader": {
          "orderType": "MCOE",
          "esoNumber": "TLVKK00",
          "rushFlag": "0",
          "serialNumber": "CA900319",
          "enteredDate": "20220110082146",
          "customerFacilityCode": "LE",
          "GSIOrderNumber": "DS0000000055068",
          "customerCode": "Z319"
        },
        "OrderDetails": [
          {
            "deliverToCoordinates": "S-X=ILCMC ",
            "exactQuantityFlag": "Y",
            "earlyShipDate": "20220110082146",
            "deliverToDockBuilding": "LE",
            "kanbanNumber": "SAMG 047877",
            "preferredWarehouseId": "",
            "deliverToBuilding": "B",
            "buildDate": "20211208000000",
            "deliverToDropZoneArea": "04M",
            "orderQuantity": 8,
            "startOnLineDate": "20211207000000",
            "warehouseId": "",
            "crossdockFlag": 0,
            "deliverToArea": "04M",
            "partNumber": "7K1181",
            "buildSequenceNumber": "012",
            "deliverToDropZoneBuilding": "B ",
            "orderLineNumber": 90,
            "deliverToDockArea": "DOCK"
          },
          {
            "deliverToCoordinates": "S-X=ILCMC ",
            "exactQuantityFlag": "Y",
            "earlyShipDate": "20220110082146",
            "deliverToDockBuilding": "LE",
            "kanbanNumber": "SAMG 020472",
            "preferredWarehouseId": "",
            "deliverToBuilding": "B",
            "buildDate": "20211208000000",
            "deliverToDropZoneArea": "04M",
            "orderQuantity": 4,
            "startOnLineDate": "20211207000000",
            "warehouseId": "",
            "crossdockFlag": 0,
            "deliverToArea": "04M",
            "partNumber": "6V8398",
            "buildSequenceNumber": "012",
            "deliverToDropZoneBuilding": "B ",
            "orderLineNumber": 173,
            "deliverToDockArea": "DOCK"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

JSON Ouput Required -

Single Flattened JSON :

```json
[
  {
    "GSIOrderNumber": "SHIVAM1000000100",
    "Orderdetails.deliverToCoordinates": " SUPRA2RA",
    "Orderdetails.exactQuantityFlag": "",
    "Orderdetails.earlyShipDate": "20220324190249",
    "Orderdetails.deliverToDockBuilding": "JA",
    "Orderdetails.preferredWarehouseId": "SE92",
    "Orderdetails.deliverToBuilding": "A2",
    "Orderdetails.deliverToDropZoneArea": " A2A",
    "Orderdetails.orderQuantity": 100,
    "Orderdetails.orderMethod": "P",
    "Orderdetails.plannedFirmIndicator": "F",
    "Orderdetails.transactionType": "A",
    "Orderdetails.lateShipDate": "",
    "Orderdetails.crossdockFlag": 0,
    "Orderdetails.deliverToArea": " A2A",
    "Orderdetails.partNumber": "2T3001",
    "Orderdetails.buildSequenceNumber": "",
    "Orderdetails.deliverToDropZoneBuilding": "A2",
    "Orderdetails.orderLineNumber": 1,
    "Orderdetails.deliverToDockArea": "DOJA"
  }
]
```

Jolt Spec i Tried is working for Input 2 but not for Input 1 :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "OrderInfo": {
          "*": {
            "OrderDetails": {
              "*": {
                "@(2,OrderHeader.GSIOrderNumber)": "[&].GSIOrderNumber",
                "*": "[&1].Orderdetails\\.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Pls help I m having difficulty in writing a jolt spec for different JSON inputs. I need to get a generic jolt spec so that i get a flattened json

Comment: No big problem seems to exists but there are some typoes such as `""`s should be replaced with `"*"`, and `[&1].Orderdetails\.&` with `[&1].Orderdetails\\.&` or even `[&1].&2\.&`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Edited the Jolt spec. I have edited the Input 1, the jolt spec does not seem to work for Modified Input 1. It is coming like this

Comment: you're welcome, can you retry after populating asterisk wildcards. I can reproduce and get the desired results through [Jolt Transform Demo](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/)

Comment: Yes Astreik wildcards works. But still the jolt spec is not working for Input 1. Struggling for 2 days, Any help is much appreciated

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Can you give the jolt spec, which works for Input 1 and Input 2. Pls take the latest Input 1 which i hv modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shift transformation specs would produce the desired outputs per each of the input

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "OrderInfo": {
          "*": {
            "OrderDetails": {
              "*": {
                "@(2,OrderHeader.GSIOrderNumber)": "[&3].&1.GSIOrderNumber",
                "*": "[&3].&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where one more layer to be added(by using `&1`), and seperate the objects at a higher level(by using `[&3]`), then get rid of the objects keys within the last spec.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check for couple of other input jsons and will update